# Стиль изложения материала в учебниках по математике

Tags: стилистика

Как определить стиль изложения материала в школьных учебниках по математике?

Это подстиль научного стиля?

Answer (score 2):

Весь учебник написан в разных стилях.

Разнообразные правила и определения написаны в **научном стиле**:

> НОК двух целых чисел m и n есть наименьшее натуральное число, которое делится на m и n без остатка.

Некоторые задачи могут быть и в **художественном**:

> Михаил Петрович шёл по дороге и считал деревья. Он насчитал 9 клёнов, 7 берёз и 6 осин. Остановившись, Михаил Петрович начал складывать все посчитанные им деревья. У него получилось 20. Прав ли Михаил Петрович?

Предисловие обычно в **официально-деловом**:

> Сборник содержит полный набор самостоятельных и контрольных работ по всему курсу 9 класса. Контрольные работы рассчитаны на один урок, самостоятельные работы на 25-40 минут, в зависимости от темы и уровня подготовки учащихся...

Comment: А изложение правил, предшествующее их формулировкам? Когда учащихся подводяь к определению. "Представьте себе, что есть 6 яблок. Вы можете поделить их..."